# Print top N files by word count in two columns

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to make a script that prints the filenames for the top *n* files from two directories (*n* being the number of files I give in in the command line) in order of number of words they have. My biggest problem however is in the way they should be displayed.

Say my command line looks like this:

```
myscript.sh 5 dir1 dir2
```

The output should have 2 columns: on the left the top 5 files in descending order from dir1, and on the right the top 5 files in descending order from dir2.

This is what I have in terms of code, however I'm missing something. I think that `pr -m -t` should do what i want, but I couldn't make it work.

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$1
dir2=$2
for files in "$dir"
do  
    find ./reuters-topics/$dir -type f -exec wc -l {} + | sort -rn |head -n 15    
done
for files in "$dir2"
do
    find ./reuters-topics/$dir2 -type f -exec wc -l {} + | sort -rn | head -n 15 
    
done
```

Comment: In the text you mention 'word count', but your example uses `wc -l` (line count). FYI.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution in fish:

```
for i in (find . -type f); wc -l $i; end | sort -rn | head -n15 | awk '{print $2 "\t" $1}'
```

As you can see, the re-ordering (filename first, number of words second) is done by `awk`. As a separator I use a tab character:

```
awk '{print $2 "\t" $1}'
```

The difference between my loop and your find call, btw, is that I do not get the "total" line in the output.
I did not test if this (including awk) also works well for files with spaces in the name.

Comment: hey! I tried it but i get the error ' syntax error near unexpected token `(' ', also i don't know anything about fish

Comment: Just take in the information I provided. Add the awk statement at the end of your statement with another pipe.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

_top_files_by_words_usage() {
  local usage=""
  read -r -d '' usage <<-"EOF"
    Usage:
        top_files_by_words <show_count> <dir1> <dir2>
    EOF
  1>&2 printf "%s\n" "$usage"
}

top_files_by_words() {
  if (( $# != 3 )) || [[ "$1" != +([0-9]) ]]; then
    _top_files_by_words_usage
    return 1
  fi

  local -i showCount=0
  local dir1=""
  local dir2=""

  showCount="$1"
  dir1="$2"
  dir2="$3"

  shopt -s extglob
  
  if [[ ! -d "$dir1" ]]; then
    1>&2 printf "directory '%s' does not exist or is not a directory\n" "$dir1"
    return 1
  fi

  if [[ ! -d "$dir2" ]]; then
    1>&2 printf "directory '%s' does not exist or is not a directory\n" "$dir2"
    return 1
  fi

  local -a out1=()
  local -a out2=()

  IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a out1 < <(find "$dir1" -type f -exec wc -w {} \; | sort -k 1gr | head -n "$showCount")
  IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a out2 < <(find "$dir2" -type f -exec wc -w {} \; | sort -k 1gr | head -n "$showCount")

  local -i i=0
  local -i maxLen=0
  local -i len=0;
  for ((i = 0; i < showCount; ++i)); do
    len="${#out1[$i]}"
    if (( len > maxLen )); then
      maxLen=$len
    fi
    # len="${#out2[$i]}"
    # if (( len > maxLen )); then
    #   maxLen=$len
    # fi
  done

  for (( i = 0; i < showCount; ++i)); do
    printf "%-*.*s %s\n" "$maxLen" "$maxLen" "${out1[$i]}" "${out2[$i]}"
  done
    
  return 0
}

top_files_by_words "$@"
```

```
$ ~/tmp/count_words.bash 15 tex tikz
 2309328 tex/resume.log                                       9692402 tikz/tikz-Graphics in LaTeX with TikZ.mp4
 2242997 tex/resume_cv.log                                    2208818 tikz/tikz-Tikz-Graphs and Automata.mp4
 2242969 tex/cover_letters/resume_cv.log                       852631 tikz/tikz-Drawing Automata with TikZ in LaTeX.mp4
   73859 tex/pgfplots/plotdata/heightmap.dat                   711004 tikz/tikz-tutorial.mp4
   49152 tex/pgfplots/lena.dat                                 300038 tikz/.ipynb_checkpoints/TikZ 11 Design Principles-checkpoint.ipynb
   43354 tex/nancy.mp4                                         300038 tikz/TikZ 11 Design Principles.ipynb
   31226 tex/pgfplots/pgfplotstodo.tex                         215583 tikz/texample/bridges-of-konigsberg.svg
   26000 tex/pgfplots/plotdata/ou.dat                          108040 tikz/Visual TikZ.pdf
   20481 tex/pgfplots/pgfplotstable.tex                         82540 tikz/worldflags.pdf
   19571 tex/pgfplots/pgfplots.reference.3dplots.tex            37608 tikz/texample/india-map.tex
   19561 tex/pgfplots/plotdata/risingdrop3d_coord.dat           35798 tikz/.ipynb_checkpoints/TikZ-checkpoint.ipynb
   19561 tex/pgfplots/plotdata/risingdrop3d_vel.dat             35656 tikz/texample/periodic_table.svg
   18207 tex/pgfplots/ChangeLog                                 35501 tikz/TikZ.ipynb
   17710 tex/pgfplots/pgfplots.reference.markers-meta.tex       25677 tikz/tikz-Graphics in LaTeX with TikZ.info.json
   13800 tex/pgfplots/pgfplots.reference.axisdescription.tex    14760 tikz/tikz-Tikz-Graphs and Automata.info.json
```

Comment: Hey! thank you for your reply! However when trying to check your solution, I get some errors regarding EOF, and since I don't know anything about that, I tried just removing that part altogether. After doing that, I get the error "subdirectory does not exist or is not a directory". To give more details, I am trying to run this inside a directory which has 2 more subdirectories, which I include in the command line

Comment: Hmn. I've run it with different relative and absolute paths and it works for me. Are you sure you copied the whole script into a file? (It's a little too long for S-O, so it scrolls. The whole last line is `top_files_by_words "$@"`

Comment: Could you paste the error you see here? Also, I am running version 5.1.16(1)-release. (`echo $BASH_VERSION`). When I tested on an old version I happen to have 3.2.57(1)-release, it complains about line 13. You can replace that line with
`if (( $# != 3 )); then` (replacing `if (( $# != 3 )) || [[ "$1" != +([0-9]) ]]; then`) and it will work. It just won't check that you actually provided a number for the first argument.

Comment: Hey, sorry for replying so late. The exact error is: "line 8: crude: No such file or directory". I tried replacing the 13th line too, and it's the same

Comment: line 8 is: `1>&2 printf "%s\n" "$usage"` ??

Answer (score 0):

`column` can print files side-by-side in columns. You can use [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) with `<(command)` to have those "files" be live commands instead of actual files.

```
#!/bin/bash

top-files() {
    local n="$1"
    local dir="$2"

    find "$dir" -type f -exec wc -l {} + |
        head -n -1 | sort -rn | head -n "$n"
}

n="$1"
dir1="$2"
dir2="$3"

column <(top-files "$n" reuters-topics/"$dir1") \
       <(top-files "$n" reuters-topics/"$dir2")
```

Comment: Cool. How did I not know about `column`? :-)

Comment: Hey! Thank you, I tried your solution but it doesn't print into columns for some reason. Also I checked the files to see if it gives me the right ones and it's not quite right :-?

Comment: Nevermind, the files displayed are the right ones after double checking, thank you